# Multithreaded performance (with Rust)

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have been running the following experiment to test multi-threaded performance in Rust.

The below piece of code basically does the following :

STEP 1: Generate 50 million random `(key, value)` pairs on the main thread.

STEP 2: Process the 50 million pairs by inserting them in a `HashMap`. This processing step is repeated simultaneously over `count` threads. Every thread has it's own HashMap.

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::time::Instant;

fn generate_values(count: usize) -> Vec<([u8; 3], u8)>{
  let mut generator = rand::thread_rng();
  let mut values = Vec::new();
  for _ in 0..count {
    let key = generator.gen::<[u8; 3]>();
    let value = generator.gen::<u8>();
    values.push((key, value));
  }
  values
}

fn process_values(values: &Arc<Vec<([u8; 3], u8)>>, count: usize) {
  let mut handles = Vec::new();
  for _ in 0..count {
    let values = Arc::clone(values);
    handles.push(thread::spawn(move || {
      let mut map = HashMap::new();
      for (key, value) in values.iter() {
        map.insert(key, value);
      }
    }));
  }
  for handle in handles {
    handle.join().unwrap();
  }
}

fn main() {
  let values = Arc::new(generate_values(50000000));
  
  println!("processing values...");
  for count in 1..=16 {
    let start = Instant::now();
    process_values(&values, count);
    println!("processing values, repeated over {} thread(s), took {:?}", count, start.elapsed());
  }
}
```

I am running the code on a dedicated server with one `AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core` processor and 64 GB of RAM, running Ubuntu 20.04. Nothing else is running on the server.

I would have expected that running the code repeated over 1 to 8 threads would have taken roughly the same amount of time, but it seems that running the code on 8 threads took about 23% more time (19.59s) than running it over 1 thread (15.97s) :

```
processing values, repeated over 1 thread(s), took 15.970677367s
processing values, repeated over 2 thread(s), took 15.936398062s
processing values, repeated over 3 thread(s), took 16.497970587s
processing values, repeated over 4 thread(s), took 17.233953355s
processing values, repeated over 5 thread(s), took 17.233057743s
processing values, repeated over 6 thread(s), took 18.223844841s
processing values, repeated over 7 thread(s), took 19.094954912s
processing values, repeated over 8 thread(s), took 19.592578442s
processing values, repeated over 9 thread(s), took 21.152438731s
processing values, repeated over 10 thread(s), took 22.881476672s
processing values, repeated over 11 thread(s), took 22.97713133s
processing values, repeated over 12 thread(s), took 23.841287249s
processing values, repeated over 13 thread(s), took 24.713425745s
processing values, repeated over 14 thread(s), took 24.979827585s
processing values, repeated over 15 thread(s), took 25.78961309s
processing values, repeated over 16 thread(s), took 26.511473666s
```

Then I thought that it had something to do with hyper-threading, so I disabled simultaneous multi-threading :

```
echo off > /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control
```

These are the results without hyper-threading :

```
processing values, repeated over 1 thread(s), took 15.906120824s
processing values, repeated over 2 thread(s), took 15.927443081s
processing values, repeated over 3 thread(s), took 16.701871709s
processing values, repeated over 4 thread(s), took 16.73429606s
processing values, repeated over 5 thread(s), took 17.785883476s
processing values, repeated over 6 thread(s), took 18.171144237s
processing values, repeated over 7 thread(s), took 18.871619003s
processing values, repeated over 8 thread(s), took 19.439770035s
processing values, repeated over 9 thread(s), took 22.937699259s
processing values, repeated over 10 thread(s), took 25.164055752s
processing values, repeated over 11 thread(s), took 29.44375459s
processing values, repeated over 12 thread(s), took 30.436276538s
processing values, repeated over 13 thread(s), took 33.775704733s
processing values, repeated over 14 thread(s), took 35.962573012s
processing values, repeated over 15 thread(s), took 38.04670196s
processing values, repeated over 16 thread(s), took 40.535251291s
```

Still the same unexpected 22-23% performance decrease when going from 1 to 8 threads.
Although the performance when going from 8 to 16 threads is consistent and as expected (it takes about twice the time to run the code on 16 threads versus 8 threads).

Here is a little graph of the relative time taken to run the code on `count` threads versus 1 thread.

[image]

Is such a performance decrease of 22-23% expected when repeating the code over 8 threads versus 1 thread, when run on an 8-core processor ?

In other words, what explains the performance decrease ?

Code is run in release with "cargo run --release".

Comment: Were you running an optimized build? What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: I'm curious why you're using `Arc` - your program is deterministic, so I don't see why you need reference-counting.

Comment: You need to add more profiling points to your program - there's a few places inside `process_values` that probably _shouldn't_ be measured, such as when you're cloning `values` for each thread - that's probably the main reason.

Comment: Run in release with "cargo run --release".

Comment: I believe the Arc is necessary because otherwise you can't be passing into the thread. Cloning an Arc is cheap (it's not deep copying the underlying values), so that can't possibly explain a 4 seconds difference !

Comment: I wasn't referring to `Arc.clone()`, I was referring to `move ||` - because that [causes all referenced objects/values to be copied into the closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.move.html). What happens if you remove the `move` keyword?

Comment: The code doesn't compile when removing the "move" : closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `values`, which is owned by the current function.

Comment: Amdahl's law rules.  There is likely to be contention between the threads over the lock that keeps the heap thread-safe.  Both in HashMap::new (minor) and map.insert.  Which needs to grow the hashmap as more items are added. You'd strongly favor setting the *capacity* up front so the heap lock is taken only once.

Comment: What's the question here? Multithreading has inherent costs -- it only makes sense to use when the **advantage you get from parallelizing your algorithms** balances out the **inherent cost of multithreading**. Your algorithms are not parallel at all -- you're just doing the same thing in a bunch of different threads. You *should always expect* that adding threads, without doing algorithm work, will slow a program down.

Comment: Sure, I get that. The full program is much more complex, and is of course dividing work over different threads to bring the total time down. I was just trying to understand why I am not seeing the performance increase I was expecting, which partly seems to come from the fact that running 8 threads adds 23% more time then running running 1 thread. The program shown here is deliberately simplified to point to that.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried by initialising the HashMap with HashMap::with_capacity(50000000) (which is definitely more than enough because there are only 2^24 = 16M key possibilities) and the result is the same.

Comment: Two possibilities:

1) Memory and Caches are a shared resource and speed when running more code in parallel is constrained on this resource. You can get some clues with `perf stat`, e.g. if there are more cache misses.

2) Modern processors run with a higher frequency if only a few cores are active. For the Ryzen / 3700 X in turbo mode the CPU runs with up to 4.4GHz while the base clock rate is only 3.6GHz.

Comment: @HHK Thanks that is a very helpful comment. If you put that in an answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- Even without lock contention memory and caches are a shared resource and speed when running more code in parallel is constrained on this resource. You can get some clues with `perf stat`, e.g. if there are more cache misses.
- Modern processors run with a higher frequency if only a few cores are active. For the Ryzen / 3700 X in turbo mode the CPU runs with up to 4.4GHz while the base clock rate is only 3.6GHz.